# How to correct forman JSON by GOlang?

Tags: json, http, go

I'm working with the Notion API and I can't use JSON correctly to send

My JSON:

```
{"parent":{"database_id":"123456"},"properties":{"Description":{"title":[{"text":{"content":"text1"}}]},"Value":{"rich_text":[{"text":{"content":"text2"}}]},"Status":{"rich_text":[{"text":{"content":"text4"
}}]},"Golang":{"rich_text":[{"text":{"content":"huinya"}}]},"Checkbox":{"Done?":true}}}
```

All correct Everything is correct except for the last paragraph.

```
"Checkbox":{"Done?":true}}}
```

Its must look like this :

```
{
  "Done?": {
    "checkbox": true
  }
}
```

My data structure in Go big, and u can see it here [go.dev](https://go.dev/play/p/oH8nN2kwOac)

changind by place data structure

Answer (score 0):

Add new type struct I put inside a map with string as key and bool as a value and in the tag add the json key that you want to have after marshalling
I hope this code can help you

```
type Done struct {
        Done map[string]bool `json:"Done?"`
    }
    Js := Done{
        Done: map[string]bool{
            "checkbox": true,
        },
    }
    b, err := json.Marshal(&Js)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
```